# Hibernate initialize SessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate

I found there are two ways to initialize hibernate SessionFactory,

1. via org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration, hibernate.cfg.xml is read for configuration and I will have java code

   > SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
2. via org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean bean and I will have java code

   > @Autowire
   >      private SessionFactory sessionFactory

Both get me the results as expected. But is there any difference in terms of application usage? For example, web application seems to prefer method 2 as the tutorials I read were configured in that way.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in method 2 you let spring configure the session instead of doing it *manually*. What I consider a better approach if you are using spring framework.